# Dictionary in C by using lists and 26 heads

Tags: c

I am trying to make a dictionary in C, kind of. I though it like this:

- make 26 little lists, for each one corresponding a head[first letter], so I'll have head[A/a], head[B/b] and so on...
- print the lists.
  Right now I'm trying to insert the elements, but I do not know what have I done wrong in this code:

  ```
  struct g_node{//declaration of a list
     char *info; // represents the value/text
     int counterWord;
     struct g_node *next; // represents the link
  };



  void push_word_begining(int initial, struct g_node *heads[initial], char *word){

      struct g_node *new_element = malloc(sizeof(struct g_node));

     strcpy(new_element->info, word);//put the word in the list
     new_element->next = heads[initial]->next; 
     heads[initial]->next = new_element; // make the link

  }

  void print_words( int initial, struct g_node *heads[initial]){//prints the list
     struct g_node *iterator = heads[initial];

     printf("\n List: ");
     while (iterator->next != NULL) {
             printf("%s ", iterator->next->info);
             iterator = iterator->next;
     }
  }


  int main()
  {
      int indexHeads;

      struct g_node *heads[26];

      for( indexHeads = 0; indexHeads < 26; indexHeads++){
              heads[indexHeads] = malloc(sizeof(struct g_node));
              heads[indexHeads]->next = NULL;
      }

      char *text = "Jim wants to be a programmer";
      char *token = strtok(text, " ");
      int initial;

      while( token != 0){
              initial = token[0];
              push_word_begining(initial, &heads[initial], token);
              token = strtok('\0', " ");
      }

      print_words(initial, &heads[initial]);


  return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: You should describe the "wrong" behavior of your program. Btw, a typical "dictionary" implementation would use a hashtable, but of course, taking the first letter is *some* kind of hashing

Comment: I do not know what is wrong, but it does not work. Probably somewhere it enters an infinite loop...

Comment: I suggest to try split the problem for smaller ones. Do you have a working and tested queue implementation? Are you confident in the code? After that you can use the list abstract to build more complicated functionality on it. BTW, from the first glance at your code I can tell that you are wasting memory for empty nodes at the beginning of the list, instead of just set head to NULL.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski that's what I tried to do, my final task is more difficult, and these two functions are basic. I am not sure of my code and I do not know what I did wrong in the implementations of these two functions...that's what I am asking..

Comment: Those two functions and data structure could be split into two simpler tasks. 1. Create a list. That means function to add a node, remove a node and walk through the list. When adding a node you need to answer a question: add new nodes at the beginning, at the end or in some order? Test the operations on the list carefully. If that works, over that add a new abstraction for dictionary. Which would be, basically, array of pointers to the 26 heads and calling the add function for a proper head. BTW, I cannot find the logic when you translate first character of token to a proper index.

Comment: @BaciuLidiaAna-Maria I suggest you go write some `printf` with different messages in some points that are risky of infinite loops, segmentation faults etc. and see while excecuting , what parts worked, and where the problem lies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could analyze this a lot easier using a debugger, this directly reveals the first problem:

```
# compile:
$ gcc -O0 -g3 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -osimpledict simpledict.c
$ gdb ./simpledict
GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1
[...]
(gdb) r
Starting program: /mnt/storage/felix/stackoverflow/simpledict/simpledict 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strtok () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S:186
186 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
(gdb) bt
#0  strtok () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strtok.S:186
#1  0x000000000040073a in main () at simpledict.c:46
(gdb)
```

so, the call to `strtok()` results in a crash. This is because you give `strtok()` a pointer to a string constant, and although string constants are of type `char *` in C, they are **read only** (and `strtok()` tries to change the string it works on by inserting `0` bytes).

so, change

```
char *text = "Jim wants to be a programmer";
```

giving you a pointer to a string constant to

```
char text[] = "Jim wants to be a programmer";
```

This way, you have a writable array of `char` that is only *initialized* from a string constant.

***Next test:***

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /mnt/storage/felix/stackoverflow/simpledict/simpledict 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S:135
135 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strcpy_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strcpy.S:135
#1  0x000000000040061d in push_word_begining (initial=74, 
    heads=0x7fffffffe040, word=0x7fffffffddd0 "Jim") at simpledict.c:17
#2  0x00000000004007b2 in main () at simpledict.c:51
(gdb) up
#1  0x000000000040061d in push_word_begining (initial=74, 
    heads=0x7fffffffe040, word=0x7fffffffddd0 "Jim") at simpledict.c:17
17     strcpy(new_element->info, word);//put the word in the list
(gdb) p *new_element
$1 = {
  info = 0x0, 
  counterWord = 0, 
  next = 0x0
}
(gdb)
```

As you can see here, `new_element->info` is `0` (or: `NULL`), an invalid pointer, still you try to copy some data there.

You first have to allocate memory for your content:

```
struct g_node *new_element = malloc(sizeof(struct g_node));

new_element->info = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);// allocate memory
strcpy(new_element->info, word);//put the word in the list
new_element->next = heads[initial]->next; 
heads[initial]->next = new_element; // make the link
```

***Next test, next crash:***

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /mnt/storage/felix/stackoverflow/simpledict/simpledict 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400696 in push_word_begining (initial=74, heads=0x7fffffffe040, 
    word=0x7fffffffddd0 "Jim") at simpledict.c:19
19     new_element->next = heads[initial]->next; 
(gdb) p *heads
$1 = (struct g_node *) 0x7fffffffe46f
(gdb) p **heads
$2 = {
  info = 0x732f746e6d2f3d5f <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x732f746e6d2f3d5f>, 
  counterWord = 1634889588, 
  next = 0x6174732f78696c65
}
(gdb)
```

Something is **very** wrong here. Your `initial` argument is `74` (and I thought it should be between `0` and `25`?), and your `*heads` points to some garbage location, well outside your array.

Well, I can see the bug:

```
        initial = token[0];
        push_word_begining(initial, &heads[initial], token);
```

`token[0]` will be the *ascii value* of your first character, which is definitely not what you want.

Add some code to actually compute the correct array index

```
        initial = token[0];
        if (initial >= 'a' && initial <= 'z') initial -= 'a';
        else if (initial >= 'A' && initial <= 'Z') initial -= 'A';
        else break; // not a letter, can't store this in your scheme
        push_word_begining(initial, &heads[initial], token);
```

It's still crashing and I skip the `gdb` output because it's not so obvious. First let's "sanitize" your function prototype. Instead of

```
void push_word_begining(int initial, struct g_node *heads[initial], char *word)
```

(the "initial" indexer in the prototype has no meaning), just write:

```
void push_word_begining(int initial, struct g_node **heads, char *word)
```

This form makes it explicit that you will get a *pointer to a pointer*

You **call** this function with

```
push_word_begining(initial, &heads[initial], token);
```

so, you pass a pointer to an individual array member already. Still, inside this function, you have code like

```
new_element->next = heads[initial]->next;
heads[initial]->next = new_element; // make the link
```

that **again** applies an index. This doesn't make much sense and these indices will just *add up* in this case. Fix it like this:

```
new_element->next = (*heads)->next;
(*heads)->next = new_element; // make the link
```

And suddenly you see that you don't even need your `initial` argument!

The same error is in your `print_words()` function. Change

```
struct g_node *iterator = heads[initial];
```

to

```
struct g_node *iterator = *heads;
```

Now, your program doesn't crash any more. Still it only prints

> List: programmer

because you only pass it your last list that was written to.

Try this instead:

```
for (indexHeads = 0; indexHeads < 26; ++indexHeads)
{
    print_words(&heads[indexHeads]);
}
puts(""); // newline at the end
```

Now the output looks like this:

> List: a
>   List: be
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List: Jim
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List: programmer
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:
>   List: to
>   List:
>   List:
>   List: wants
>   List:
>   List:
>   List:

For reference, here's the code with the applied fixes:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct g_node{//declaration of a list
   char *info; // represents the value/text
   int counterWord;
   struct g_node *next; // represents the link
};



void push_word_begining(struct g_node **heads, char *word){

    struct g_node *new_element = malloc(sizeof(struct g_node));

    new_element->info = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);// allocate memory    
   strcpy(new_element->info, word);//put the word in the list
   new_element->next = (*heads)->next; 
   (*heads)->next = new_element; // make the link

}

void print_words(struct g_node **heads){//prints the list
   struct g_node *iterator = *heads;

   printf("\n List: ");
   while (iterator->next != NULL) {
           printf("%s ", iterator->next->info);
           iterator = iterator->next;
   }
}


int main()
{
    int indexHeads;

    struct g_node *heads[26];

    for( indexHeads = 0; indexHeads < 26; indexHeads++){
            heads[indexHeads] = malloc(sizeof(struct g_node));
            heads[indexHeads]->next = NULL;
    }

    char text[] = "Jim wants to be a programmer";
    char *token = strtok(text, " ");
    int initial;

    while( token != 0){
            initial = token[0];
            initial = token[0];
            if (initial >= 'a' && initial <= 'z') initial -= 'a';
            else if (initial >= 'A' && initial <= 'Z') initial -= 'A';
            else break; // not a letter, can't store this in your scheme
            push_word_begining(&heads[initial], token);
            token = strtok(0, " ");
    }

    for (indexHeads = 0; indexHeads < 26; ++indexHeads)
    {
        print_words(&heads[indexHeads]);
    }
    puts("");


return 0;
}
```

There's still a lot to do, e.g. test with more than one word with the same initial, free your memory when you're done, etc.

And, try to learn how to use a debugger, it will help you a lot.